# Creating an alias in bash that calls a script and an additional command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, directory-structure, aliases

I was toying with the idea of creating an alias that would allow me to list the contents of a target subdirectory, without changing to that directory.

I have successfully been able to create both an alias and a script to change directory and display contents. I call the script **leap** and it is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:.

# script to change to a directory, then display current contents
cd $1 && ls -l -a
```

The alias I use to trigger **leap** is defined: `alias lp='. ~/scripts/leap'`

My hope was I could simply create an alias named **pk** (pk is for peek) and concatenate my **leap** script and a standard bash command using `&&`. I could not be more wrong.

## Current Directory

For reference, here is the contents of my current home directory (my user id has been replaced with $$$$):

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 $$$$$$    46374   23 Aug 30 11:40 Fall_2019
drwxr-xr-x 5 $$$$$$    46374   66 Aug 28 09:01 PAST_COURSES
drwxr-xr-x 3 $$$$$$    46374   22 Aug 30 12:03 repos
drwxr-xr-x 3 $$$$$$ students  117 Aug 31 09:06 scripts
```

## The Attempt(s)

Using `alias pk='lp $1 && cd ..'`
Entering `[$$$$@host ~]$ pk PAST_COURSES` results in:

```
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students  1766 Feb 28  2018 ~
drwx------   10 $$$$$$ students  4096 Aug 31 09:06 .
drwx--x--x 1232 root   root     28672 Aug 30 16:03 ..
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students 11368 Aug 30 12:20 .bash_history
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students    18 Aug 21  2017 .bash_logout
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students   180 Mar  8  2018 .bash_profile
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students   526 Aug 30 11:19 .bashrc
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students   266 Aug 21  2017 .cshrc
drwxr-xr-x    3 $$$$$$     46374    23 Aug 30 11:40 Fall_2019
drwxr-xr-x    8 $$$$$$ students   155 Aug 30 12:14 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 $$$$$$ students    87 Apr 11  2018 .gitconfig
-rw-r--r--    1 $$$$$$ students 12288 Jan 29  2018 .hello.swp
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students   172 Aug 21  2017 .kshrc
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students   189 Mar 13  2018 .lesshst
-rw-r--r--    1 $$$$$$ students 20480 Jan 29  2018 .ls.swn
drwxr-xr-x    5 $$$$$$ 46374    66 Aug 28 09:01 PAST_COURSES
drwxr-----    3 $$$$$$ 46374    18 Aug 30 12:16 .pki
drwxr-xr-x    3 $$$$$$ 46374    22 Aug 30 12:03 repos
drwxr-xr-x    3 $$$$$$ students   117 Aug 31 09:06 scripts
drwx------    3 $$$$$$ students   103 Aug 30 11:12 .ssh
-rw-------    1 $$$$$$ students 12288 Sep  6  2017 .swp
drwxr-xr-x    2 $$$$$$ 46374    23 Aug 31 09:06 .vim
-rw-r--r--    1 $$$$$$ students  8129 Aug 31 09:06 .viminfo
-rw-r--r--    1 $$$$$$ students   142 Feb 14  2018 .vimrc
[$$$$@host home]$
```

As you can see, this displays the current directory ( ~ ) rather than switching to PAST_COURSES and displaying it. Additionally, the alias jumps up one directory above the current directory ( ~ ) rather than returning to it from PAST_COURSES.

Incidentally, I also get this exact result when I try using the following aliases:

`pk='. ~/scripts/leap $1 && cd ..'`
(using the script for **leap** rather than the alias)

`pk='cd $1 && ls -l -a && cd ..'`
(using the exact code inside **leap** )

## Findings

In my tinkering I have noticed a few things:

- First, if I simply type `$$$$@host ~]$ ~/scripts/leap *[dir-name]*` I actually get EXACTLY what I want - a look into a directory without changing to it. All by omitting the leading `.`, which boggles me.
- Second, I can fix the current pk alias by changing the trailing  `cd ..` to `cd $(pwd)`, though it will not display the target directory instead of the current one.

At this point, I'd like a little help - not just in a script or alias that will do the job. An explanation that explains this behavior that I'm seeing would be marvelous.

Comment: hello, sorry but do you think you could help clarify what it is that you are asking about?

Comment: So, I use LS and CD constantly. But it becomes a pain to constantly have to pop in and out of directories looking for the file I want to work on. I'd like an alias I can use that displays the contents of a directory, without moving to that directory. 

I already wrote a script that jumps to a directory and displays the contents. I was hoping I could just modify it to return to the original directory as well.

It hasn't gone well and the above entry is a list of what I've tried.

Does this clarify things ?

Comment: Use a function. See: `help function`

Comment: I am not getting it, you do know you don't have to `cd` into a directory first before you can run `ls` to list the items inside it? I meant what's wrong with just doing `ls -al [whatever_path]` without messing with the pwd?

Comment: I did know that. But I find the longer the command, the more mistakes I make! lol

It's just a matter of preference, but I would rather invoke a function or script with a short alias rather than repeatedly having to re-enter a long, specific command line statement ... which would be vulnerable to typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't use `.` (the source builtin)

```sh
alias pk='. ~/scripts/leap $1 && cd ..' (using the script for leap rather than the alias)
```

is not equivalent to

```sh
alias pk='cd $1 && ls -l -a && cd ..'
```

In the first one, the `.` builtin (also known as `source`) is used, while in the second it is not. `.` doesn't just execute a command, it executes it in *the current shell context*. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> . (a period)
>
> `. filename [arguments]`
>
> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current shell context.

That means anything the script does effects your current shell context. If the script changes directories, so does your current context.

If, on the other hand, the first version omitted the `.` like this:

```sh
alias pk='~/scripts/leap $1 && cd ..'
```

then the contents of the `leap` script would run in it's own bash context, but your current context would move up one directory (since the `cd ..` isn't inside the leap script).

## Additional Recommendation on Functions vs Aliases

You could implement `pk` using a function like this:

```
pk() {
  pushd $1

  if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    # Successfully changed directories.

    # Run command
    $2

    # Return from the pre-pushd directory.
    popd
  fi

}
```

From the [Bash Manual | 6.6 Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> For almost every purpose, [shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) are preferred over aliases.

### Example Alias

```
alias foo="echo bar"
```

### Equivalent Function

```
foo() {
    echo bar
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! I was unaware of the properties surrounding the leading period. 

I prefer aliases because they're typically easier to script (in my opinion) and I can repopulate a .bash_aliases page by hand pretty quickly when switching to new environments. 

But thanks to your suggestion, I'll have to read up on function implementation for future reference.